# Change color of drawableLeft icon in android textview

Tags: java, android, textview

How to change the color of drawable icon which is set to textview in android using drawableLeft?

Comment: show what have you tried ?  so we can suggest you a solutions

Comment: I have added drawableTint with color but not working in Android 5.1. I just want to change the color of the icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]Create a png/jpeg file of icon with specific color and use it in xml file

```
 android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon_With_Custom_color"
```

For custom Icons refrer following image [image]

Comment: I want to use predefined android icons with color change

Comment: Right click on res Folder >New >Image Assets   Resize your icon

Comment: I got images. But those are in black. How can I assign the primary color to that predefined icons in XML file?

Comment: Hope you got the right answer

Comment: No sir. I am unable to change color of icon

Comment: Then all the best for your bright future

Comment: Thank you Vikrant. Now I got answer